# How to filter same string from two arrays and display it only once

Tags: c#, linq

I have two tables in my database

1. Server table - contains list of ServerID(string datatype), ServerID is the primary key
2. Component table - contains list of Component names, ServerID is the foreign key

The following query

```
var query2 = (from a in this.db.Servers
             join b in this.db.Components
             on a.ServerID equals b.ServerID                        
             select new { a.ServerID, b.Name }).AsEnumerable().Select(x => string.Format("{0}---{1} ",x.ServerID, x.Name)).ToArray();

string[] header = query2;
```

header[] will have the following result

```
Server X component 1x
Server X component 2x
Server X component 3x
Server Y component 1y
Server Y component 2y
Server Y component 3y
Server Z component 1z
Server Z component 2z
Server Z component 3z
```

**but I would like to display the result as follows**

```
Server X
component 1x
component 2x
component 3x
Server Y
component 1y
component 2y
component 3y
Server Z
component 1z
component 2z
component 3z
```

which means pick up only the distinct ServerID once and followed by the corresponding components. to execute this I tried creating two querys. the first query to return only the distinct ServerID's and the second one as the above query and to loop and match it. but didnt work. kindly help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would group by the `ServerID` and use a `SelectMany` to concatenate each ID with the list of components:

```
var query2 = (from a in this.db.Servers
             join b in this.db.Components
             on a.ServerID equals b.ServerID                        
             select new { a.ServerID, b.Name })
             .AsEnumerable()
             .GroupBy(a => a.ServerID)
             .SelectMany(g => (new [] {g.Key}).Concat(g.Select(i=>i.Name)));

string[] header = query2.ToArray();
```

or if you want to do the grouping on the server:

```
var query2 = (from a in this.db.Servers
             join b in this.db.Components
             on a.ServerID equals b.ServerID  into g
             select new { 
                a.ServerID, 
                Components = g.Select(x => x.Name) 
             })
             .AsEnumerable()
             .SelectMany(g => (new [] {g.ServerID}).Concat(g.Components));
```

Comment: I think `Concat()` makes more sense than `Union()` here.

Comment: @svick - you are correct - if there were a server and component with the same name the component would be dropped.  Updated.

Comment: How to bind this to a datagrid ? I tried using datagrid1.ItemsSource = header.ToList(); , but I get the count of the each server as the result in the datagrid. kindly help

Comment: If you post that as a new question you'll get a lot more responses - and some rep :)

Answer (score 4):

Use group join to group components by servers:

```
var query = from a in this.db.Servers
            join b in this.db.Components
                 on a.ServerID equals b.ServerID into g
            select new { 
                a.ServerID, 
                Components = g.Select(x => x.Name) 
            };
```

---

Creating array:

```
List<string> result = new List<string>();

foreach(var server in query)
{
   result.Add(server.ServerID);
   foreach(var componentName in server.Components)
       result.Add(componentName);
}

string[] array = result.ToArray();
```

Comment: thnks for the update sir. mine is not a console application.. i have to return the query to a string array

Comment: The result of the query- groups only the serverID's and the component belonging to the server is empty

Comment: @demo_user components should be there. How are you verifying that?

Comment: i set the debugger and i can see only serverID are grouped

Comment: @demo_user each item in result query will contain two properties - ServerID and collection of component names. Can't say how you looking results in debugger, but that is how GroupJoin works

Comment: kindly have a look at this screenshot http://s16.postimg.org/lay7m23xx/output.png

Comment: @demo_user all is OK on screenshot - each server group has collection of components. If you want to see components - open server group and go to the Components property

Answer (score 1):

You can use the GroupBy LINQ operator specifying ServerID as the key; the result is a set of `IGrouping` objects, one for each ServerID, each containing a list of the records for that ServerID.

Try:

```
from a in this.db.Servers
join b in this.db.Components
on a.ServerID equals b.ServerID                        
group b.Name by a.ServerID
```